# Loop through directories, check if string exists in one file, move another file

Tags: bash, grep

I'm working on a bash script that should do the following:  for every directory beginning with Event_*, (in cat eventList), cd into the directory, and if the string "ZJ.ROT" exists in the file *.mcp, I want to copy the file "ROT" to another directory.  In simpler terms: loop through directories: if string "ZJ.ROT" exists in a file in that directory, output another file from that directory to a separate directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir newdire
for dir in `cat eventList`; do
cd $dir
pwd
if grep "ZJ.KNYN" *.mcp; then
cp "ROT" "newdire"
fi
done
```

The error I get is:

```
./azim.sh: line 5: cd: Event_2014.11.21.10.10.19.630: No such file or directory
/Users/files/Event_2013.12.01.06.29.57.800
grep: *.mcp: No such file or directory
```

For some reason, this for loop isn't looping through each directory, but it's stuck in the first directory Event_2013....  Any ideas about how to implement this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first time you `cd` to a subdirectory you are in it for all future loop iterations so your subsequent cds will fail, as you are experiencing. You also need to quote your variables and there's other issues. Try this:

```
pwd="$PWD"
mkdir newdire
while IFS= read -r dir; do
    cd "$dir"
    grep -Fq "ZJ.KNYN" *.mcp &&
    cp "ROT" "${pwd}/newdire"
    cd "$pwd"
done < eventList
```

but of course you don't actually need to cd:

```
mkdir newdire
while IFS= read -r dir; do
    grep -Fq "ZJ.KNYN" "$dir"/*.mcp &&
    cp "${dir}/ROT" newdire
done < eventList
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be here:

```
if grep "ZJ.KNYN" *.mcp; then
```

You should use `-q` option in `grep` to suppress the output and check the return status like this:

```
if grep -qF "ZJ.KNYN" *.mcp; then
```

`-F` is for fixed string search.

Also there is no need to change directory inside the loop.

Your full script can be better rewritten as:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir newdire

for dir in Event_*; do
   if [[ -d "$dir" ]] && grep -qF "ZJ.KNYN" "$dir"/*.mcp 2>/dev/null; then
      cp "$dir/ROT" "newdire/"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Any ideas as to why I would get an error where I can't cd into the directory, even though when I read the pwd, it's correct?  I for some reason can't change directories, and thus the rest of the loop cannot run..

Comment: Hm.  I'm getting an error that states: grep: ZJ.KNYN: No such file or directory.  Any ideas?  "ZJ.KNYN" is a string within a file, not a file name.

Comment: Rather, I want the if statement to be "If the string "ZJ.KNYN" exists in the file *.mcp, then cp the other file".  Is there a way in the if statement to see if the grep string exists?

Comment: `grep -qF "ZJ.KNYN" "$dir"/*.mcp` will indeed do that i.e. it will check for presence of text `ZJ.KNYN` in `*.mcp` files inside `$dir` directory.

Comment: Are you sure there is a sub-directory called: `Event_2014.11.21.10.10.19.630` from the path where script is running?

Comment: I am running the script in ~/Users/files/.  Within ~/Users/files/ there are multiple event directories, i.e. ~/User/files/Event_2013.11.21.10.10.19.630/.  I want to loop through each of these event directories, which are subdirectories located in ~/Users/files/.

Comment: Hmm.  I still get the same error grep: ZJ.KNYN: No such file or directory, repeated for however many Event directories there are.  Thanks for your patience, but do you have any other ideas?

Comment: This is a working and tested script. Why not you try to find what's wrong in your execution? I would suggest your run this script using `bash -x ./script.sh` and see why it is not working for you.